# Beamer error when using '\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}'

Tags: beamer

I'm testing some examples with Beamer, and when I run [this example](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~frank/ENG/beamer/example/beamer-class-example-en-7.html), I have this error message.

```
> \ProvidesPackageRCS=macro:
->\def \pgfrcs@marshal {\ProvidesPackage {\pgf@rcsfile }}\pgfrcs@parserest .
l.1 \show\ProvidesPackageRCS
```

I just ignore it, and return to get the pdf file anyway.

This line causes the problem

```
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
```

As replacing with this line, I have no error message at all.

```
\usetheme{Warsaw}
```

- What's wrong with this beamerthemeshadow?
- What's the difference between using \usepackage{} and \usetheme{} in Beamer?

I use MacTeX 2009.

Comment: You should use `beamerthemeshadow.sty` either as package or included in local directory.

Comment: This is what `\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}` does. Also the "either as package or included in local directory" part doesn't make much sense. You mean he should install the package either globally or in the local directory, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shadow is an old style theme, and the manual suggests using Warsaw instead.  The file you're citing is dated 2007, which means maybe the original author was used to the old conventions of `\usepackage` versus `\usetheme`.

However, the message you quote is not an error.  The first line of whatever file you're actually compiling must have `\show\ProvidesPackageRCS` in it, and the normal behavior of `\show` is to interrupt compiling and output the next token's definition.  As you note, ignoring the message doesn't cause any further compile problems.

I have MacTeX 2009 installed as well, and my `beamerthemeshadow.sty` doesn't have that in it, but maybe the one you're reading does.

Anyway, long story short, don't worry about a non-error when using an obsolescent theme.  Just use Warsaw and go about your business. `:-D`

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce the problem, since the code compiles without errors for me, and therefore not answer on the first part.

But the `\usetheme{MYTHEME}` command basically loads the file `beamerthemeMYTHEME.sty`. The actual theme is split up into several files according to some naming convention, each containing inner theme, outer theme, font theme and so on. The main theme package loads the other files like `beamerfontthemeMYTHEME.sty` and so forth.

The `\usepackage` command just includes the one package you specify. You can replace `\usetheme{MYTHEME}` by `\usepackage{beamerthemeMYTHEME}` if you want. But it's probably better to stick to the beamer guide.

I believe `beamerthemeshadow` is not part of a single big theme and thus does not follow the naming convention.

The advantage of the naming system of beamer is that you can freely combine inner and outer themes from different 'global' themes.