# Small Caps in beamer class - \rmfamily\scshape command doesn't work

Tags: beamer, small-caps, beamerposter

I'm making a poster with the  `beamer` class and want some of the text with Small Caps. I found out that the default font of the beamer class is sans serif and it does not have small capitals, but I don't want to change all my text font.

Looking [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212405/small-caps-and-bold-styles-in-beamer), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36311/use-of-scshape-or-textsc-in-beamer-institute/36320#36320) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face#27413) I tried these solutions and all possible combinations of them:

- use `{\rmfamily \scshape my text here}`
- `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
- use `\textsc{ my text here}`

But none worked. I'm trying to use the small caps along with the `\large` command, and I thought it could be the problem, but I saw someone using it with `\huge` and all worked well.

What can I do to have the small capital text without changing the entire text font?  Here is what I have, in case I'm overriding the command I want (you can see some of the combinations I tried there):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
\begin{block}

\begin{center}
    \large{{{\rmfamily\scshape Universidade} E\textsc{stadual de} {\rmfamily\textsc{Campinas}} - IMECC}} 
\end{center}
\end{block}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

P.S. I'm using a template from someone else, so I do not really understand all that is being made in this code.

UPDATE: When making the MWE, I discovered that when I remove the `bemaerthemeshadow` package, the problem disappear. But removing it from my poster made some of the text to stay with a not so pretty formatting, then I would like to keep it.

Comment: You should really read [how to create a minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that replicates your behaviour. There are so many packages here that are completely unnecessary. Think about it this way: Help us by making your code easier. This way we can help you much quicker.

Comment: unrelated to small caps but size commands do not take an argument, the syntax is `\large abc` not `\large{abc}`

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for the link. I updated the code. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beamer error when using '\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}'](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7294/beamer-error-when-using-usepackagebeamerthemeshadow)

Comment: Replace `\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}` by `\usetheme{Warsaw}`

Comment: @samcarter Using `\usetheme{Warsaw}` still made the text change its formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard fonts don't have (sans) serif boldface small caps. Thus you get almost random substitutions.

Since you seem to be using `\rmfamily`, you can get away with this (simpler) code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}


\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{block}{}
  \centering\large\rmfamily\scshape Universidade
  Estadual de Campinas - IMECC
  \end{block}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution doesn't work if I use `\usepackage{lmodern}`, but I ended up liking the text without it better than with it. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to make it work with the `lmodern`package too?

Comment: @B.Dors Latin Modern has no boldface small caps font.

Comment: But shouldn't `\rmfamily` provides the small caps?

Comment: @B.Dors The general template adds `\bfseries`; you can countermand it by doing `\normalfont` before `\rmfamily`.

Comment: `\normalfont` hasn't worked :(